# Local gulp not found when executing gulp serve

Tags: spfx, gulp, npm

I have downloaded the spfx samples from github and I am running into this problem when I execute `gulp serve`.

```
λ gulp serve
[12:39:37] Local gulp not found in C:\react-todo-basic
[12:39:37] Try running: npm install gulp
```

I used this to install gulp:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-install
```

but still getting the same error.

then I ran

```
npm install
```

then ran gulp serve again and started getting strange errors:

```
C:\react-todo-basic                                                                                              
λ gulp serve                                                                                                              
Build target: DEBUG                                                                                                       
[12:56:27] Using gulpfile C:\Projects\react-todo-basic\gulpfile.js                                                        
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined                                                                      
    at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20                                    
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)                                                        
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)                                                        
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:686:11)                                                                         
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)                                                                                 
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3                                                                                            
[12:56:27] Error - Unknown                                                                                                
 Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined                                                                                
[12:56:28] ==================[ Finished ]==================                                                               
Error - Unknown                                                                                                           
 Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined                                                                                
[12:56:28] Project react-todo-basic version: 0.0.3                                                                        
[12:56:28] Build tools version: 2.5.3                                                                                     
[12:56:28] Node version: v8.9.4                                                                                           
[12:56:28] Total duration: 2.7 s                                                                                          
[12:56:28] Task errors: 2                                                                                                 
TypeError: localCache.gulp.stop is not a function                                                                         
    at C:\react-todo-basic\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\logging.js:253:37                         
    at C:\react-todo-basic\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\logging.js:192:21                         
    at C:\react-todo-basic\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\logging.js:133:13                         
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\react-todo-basic\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\logging.js:114:17)    
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)                                                                                       
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)                                                                                     
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)                                                                              
[12:56:28] Error - Unknown                                                                                                
 localCache.gulp.stop is not a function                                                                                   
C:\react-todo-basic\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\logging.js:253                                   
                    localCache.gulp.stop();                                                                               
                                    ^                                                                                     

TypeError: localCache.gulp.stop is not a function                                                                         
    at C:\react-todo-basic\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\logging.js:253:37                         
    at writeSummary (C:\react-todo-basic\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\logging.js:202:13)          
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\react-todo-basic\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\logging.js:250:13)   
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)                                                                                         
    at process.emit (events.js:211:7)                                                                                     
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:374:26)                                                                 

C:\react-todo-basic                                                                                              
λ
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi here you go this should work, after you run bellow command:

Step-1:

```
npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint --save-dev
```

you should run the following command:

Step-2:

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

Step-3:

```
gulp trust-dev-cert
```

Make sure you allow access when popups come

step-5:

```
gulp serve
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

instead of

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-install
```

Comment: I think I have tried both options, but I will give a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Your current directory `C:\react-todo-basic` does not contain a gulpfile. Your probably have your project in a folder beneath it.

So, CD into that folder and run your gulp task.

Comment: the gulp file is in the same folder as my project.

Comment: at this moment I created a new project from scratch and copied the files there. I will continue investigating this issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

Run :
`npm link gulp`
in your application directory (to create a local link to the globally installed Gulp module)

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as Admin on your PC, so that the Popup comes up to Allow access.